# How to take a char * containing the string "$Rx", where 'x' is a number, and store the x to a an integer?

Tags: c, char, int

So I have a text file and I read in a value and store it into a char *.  This variable will always have a number, representing the register I wish to use later in the code, as the third character (i.e. $R0 or $R1, etc.).  I want to store into a pre-initialized int called register_index1.  For reference the value read in from strtok below is $R1.

I tried using:

```
    input_E_human = strtok(NULL, " ,");
    register_index1 = atoi(input_E_human[2]);
```

but that made my program error out and not compile so I read online that you could just do this:

```
    input_E_human = strtok(NULL, " ,");
    register_index1 = input_E_human[2];
```

but that's not working either.  It compiles but if I do:

```
    printf("%d",register_index);
```

it prints out the number 49, not 1.  This is (obviously) causing unexpected behavior later on in my code.  Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Does those values Always have the same length (`3`)?

Comment: Perhaps `sscanf(input_E_human, "$R%d", &register_index);`

Answer (score 1):

If it is always the third character and always one character long you can simply subtract `’0’` from it and you get it as a number. C standard requires digits to be sequential so this works.

```
register_index1 = input_E_human[2] - ‘0’;
```

Answer (score 1):

`input_E_human[2]` is the third character in `input_E_human`. But `atoi` takes a *pointer* to a sequence of characters, or in other words the *address* of the first character in the string containing the integer. That would be `&input_E_human[2]`, which could also be written `input_E_human + 2`.

Which of those you choose depends on your preferred style (I usually go with the first one but there is no hard and fast rule), but understanding why they are the same is essential for understanding C.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about the length if is `3` or not, one way will be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int ret ( const char *src );

int main(void){
    char ptr[] = "$R3";
    int number = ret( ptr );

    if ( number < 0 ){
        printf("There was no number Found!\n");
        /* do something here */
    }else{
        printf("Number = %d\n", number);
    }
}

int ret ( const char *src ){
    int i = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(src[i] != '\0' ){
        if( isdigit (src[i]) ){ // if( ( src[i] >= '0' ) && ( src[i] <= '9' )  ){}
            tmp = src[i] - '0';
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if ( count == 0 ){
        return -1;
    }else{
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Number = 3
```

Like you noticed all you need to do is to subtract `ptr[i]` with `'0'`.

Of course if there are more than one number I am sure you can now adapt the code to your needs. But If you care only for the last number, then this code is fine.

Even if you have a string like this `"$5H4j9R3"` it will still print `3` which is the last number.